# Abstract class inheriting a generic type requiring a constructor

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I've created some classes as follows:

```
abstract class TestBase<T, TThis> where TThis : TestBase<T, TThis>, new()
{
    public T Thing { get; set; }
    public static TThis CreateNew(T t)
    {
        return new TThis {Thing = t};
    }
}

abstract class MiddleClass : TestBase<string, MiddleClass>
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

class RealClass : MiddleClass
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
...
var mc = RealClass.CreateNew("Hello world");
mc.DoSomething();
```

As you can see, using this pattern I can simulate a kind of inheritance for the static method `CreateNew()`, which returns the type of the `TestBase` subclass invoked.  Works great for concrete classes that derive from `TestBase`.

Trouble is, in this particular case it won't compile, because `MiddleClass` is abstract, and therefore does not have a parameterless constructor to satisfy the `new()` constraint.

Can you think of a workaround for this, other than making `MiddleClass` concrete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make `MiddleClass` generic as well:

```
abstract class MiddleClass<T> : TestBase<string, T> where T : MiddleClass<T>, new()
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

then `RealClass` is defined as:

```
class RealClass : MiddleClass<RealClass>
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Fastest answer wins. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just make your middle class generic

```
    abstract class TestBase<T, TThis> where TThis : TestBase<T, TThis>, new()
    {
        public T Thing { get; set; }
        public static TThis CreateNew(T t)
        {
            return new TThis { Thing = t };
        }
    }

    abstract class MiddleClass<TThis> 
         : TestBase<string, TThis> where TThis : TestBase<string, TThis>, new()
    {
        public abstract void DoSomething();
    }

    class RealClass : MiddleClass<RealClass>
    {
        public override void DoSomething()
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```